# How to get hold of SOAP fault xml when using Mule 3.5.1 EE Web Service Consumer component?

Tags: soap, error-handling, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I want to know the soap fault message from web service consumer(mule component) and so I am using catch-exception-strategy to get hold of the SOAP Fault message.
But the exceptionPayload of web service consumer(mule component) does not contain the SOAP fault. While payload has the soap fault message nested deep under like:

```
payload->firstChild->firstchild->firstChild
```

Is there any way to print or process the SOAP fault from inside the catch-exception-strategy of Mule.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP Fault received from a call made to an external service is a valid soap response. 
It is not an exception in your flow. So when there is no exception, there is no exception payload.
Hence there will be no triggering of Catch Exception Strategy.

So you have to deal with the process of extracting message payload from the SOAP Fault response.

Comment: So how to get hold of SOAP fault Response, payload in this case will be [default:null] when a SOAP fault happens.